# How do I change the value in a 2d array

Tags: java

the output for this is

```
  - - -
  - - -
  - - -
  1 2 3
  4 5 6
  7 8 9
```

if I enter 1 I want the new output to be

```
  X - -
  - - -
  - - -
  1 2 3
  4 5 6
  7 8 9
```

I've tried using boolean statements and while(true) but I just can't figure it out..
Here is some sample code

```
String table[][];
table = new String[3][3];
int options[][]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};

while(true){
    for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++) {
            table[i][j] = "—";

            System.out.print(table[i][j] + " ");
    } //FOR LOOP 2
        System.out.println();
    }// FOR LOOP 1
    for (int i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < options[i].length; j++) {

            System.out.print(options[i][j]+ " ");
        }// FOR LOOP 2(2)
        System.out.println();
    }// FOR LOOP 1(1)
        // ASK FOR MOVE ONE

    System.out.println("Player One (x) : Enter a move from 1-9 >>> ");
    int x = in.nextInt();

    if (x==1){
        table[0][0]="x";
        return true; //DOES NOT WORK. I WANT IT TO RETURN TO TOP WITH THE VALUE table[0][0] = x
    }
```

When I enter 1 my output is still
    - - -
    - - -
    - - -
    1 2 3
    4 5 6
    7 8 9

Comment: how this is related to 2d array?

Comment: now it is unclear what you are asking

Comment: I just added some more code @KickButtowski

Comment: what happened if you enter another x?

Comment: @GautamSavaliya it does not matter does it? you just change a value of index that is all. you will not add more item or reduce less item hope I make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the array's initialization to be outside your while loop :

```
// init the array
for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++) {
        table[i][j] = "—";
    } 
}
while(true){
    // print the array
    for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(table[i][j] + " ");
        } 
        System.out.println();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < options[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(options[i][j]+ " ");
        }// FOR LOOP 2(2)
        System.out.println();
    }// FOR LOOP 1(1)
    // ASK FOR MOVE ONE
    System.out.println("Player One (x) : Enter a move from 1-9 >>> ");
    int x = in.nextInt();
    if (x==1){
        table[0][0]="x";
    }
}
```

This way, you won't reset the array in each iteration of the loop.

In addition, don't put a return statement in your condition, since that would break out of the loop and won't print the updated array.

Answer (score 0):

Use boolean variable flag to check condition

```
boolean flag=false;
```

In if loop assign flag true

```
if (x==1){
        table[0][0]="x";
        flag=true;
}
```

Use do...while loop instead of while loop

```
 do{

    }while(flag)
```

Below is updated code:

```
boolean flag=false;

do{
    for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++) {
            table[i][j] = "—";

            System.out.print(table[i][j] + " ");
    } //FOR LOOP 2
        System.out.println();
    }// FOR LOOP 1
    for (int i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < options[i].length; j++) {

            System.out.print(options[i][j]+ " ");
        }// FOR LOOP 2(2)
        System.out.println();
    }// FOR LOOP 1(1)
        // ASK FOR MOVE ONE

    System.out.println("Player One (x) : Enter a move from 1-9 >>> ");
    int x = in.nextInt();

    if (x==1){
        table[0][0]="x";
        flag=true;
    }
}while(flag);
```

Comment: When I do that my program doesn't go back to the top of the while loop

Comment: I did that but it still didn't add "x"

Answer (score 0):

However to fix your code the following will do.  Please plse relook your solution to simplify

```
int userInput = -1;

while(true){
    for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++) {
           if (userInput ==1){
              table[0][0]="x";
           }else {
             table[i][j] = "—";
            }

            System.out.print(table[i][j] + " ");
        } //FOR LOOP 2
        System.out.println();
    }// FOR LOOP 1
    for (int i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < options[i].length; j++) {

            System.out.print(options[i][j]+ " ");
        }// FOR LOOP 2(2)
        System.out.println();
    }// FOR LOOP 1(1)
        // ASK FOR MOVE ONE

    System.out.println("Player One (x) : Enter a move from 1-9 >>> ");
    userInput = in.nextInt();
```